# django-rest-framework - What is the equivalent of "perform_create" in APIView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Where can I set the associated model when I'm creating an object in `APIView`?

```
def perform_create(self, serializer): 
     serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

The above works in `generics.ListAPIView` but what about `APIView`? I have two models `A` and `B`. `B` has a `ForeignKey` to `A`. When creating an instance of `B` how do I set the `ForeignKey` before saving?

```
a = A.objects.get(id=request.DATA['a_id'])
serializer = BSerializer(data=request.DATA)

     if serializer.is_valid():
           b = serializer.save(a=a)
```

If I include the `a` field in `BSerializer`, this complains that `a This field is required`. If I exclude it, then it gives an `IntegrityError`. How is it supposed to be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**For Django REST Framework 3.0:**

`perform_create` is available through the generics API, which is why it works for `GenericAPIView` and any subclasses (including `ViewSet` instances).

The error you are getting is on the serializer level, before you even reach the point of `serializer.save`, so having `perform_create` wouldn't completely help you there. If the user will never be submitting the full nested representation of the object (and your serializer is expecting one), then your best bet is to make the field `read_only` and deal with it outside of the serializer by passing it into the `serializer.save` method.

**For Django REST Framework 2.4:**

`perform_create` is new in Django REST Framework 3.0, so the current documentation does not match the version you are using. If you can upgrade to Django REST Framework 3.0, it is recommended to do that.

In Django REST Framework 2.4, the serializer contains a reference to the model object that is being created or modified in the `serializer.object` attribute. For a `ModelSerializer`, this is the model object with any changes that were passed in (assuming it passed validation). Calling `serializer.save` just saves this object (while reconstructing relations), so you *can* modify it directly.

To set a foreign key relationship that is required when the object is saved or created, you just need to do...

```
serializer.object.related_field = related_object
```

...before calling `serializer.save()` (with no arguments). In Django REST Framework 2.4, any arguments passed to `serializer.save` make their way down to `model.save`, which is why you cannot use the method recommended for Django REST Framework 3.0. In 3.0, `serializer.save` allows you to pass extra arguments that will be set directly on the object that should be created (a better way of setting `serializer.validated_data`), instead of passing them into `model.save`.

Comment: using `serializer.save(myforeignkeyfield=A.Object.get(pk=1)` gives me this error: `save() got an unexpected argument...`. I would love to associate the related model with save() but this is what I'm getting. At least in version 2.4.